# Get a clear solid colour in print

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, print-design

I design catalogues. Some colours of my pallete used for small size fonts being printed look somehow dirty and not really solid & crisp (especially on a coloured background). Is there any way how to choose a better colour or tweak an existing once? For example this one: C-11 M-46 Y-97 K-37

Comment: ... How small, is small?

Comment: I would say it's small: 8pt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making text out of CMYK in the way that you have described is bad practice. There are two inherent problems with this approach:

1. The tints of the process colours are all screened, meaning that the letter shapes will be made out of lots of little dots, rather than a solid, crisp shape.
2. You are relying on perfect registration between all the colours involved, which never happens and any mis-register will give a blurred effect. The smaller the text, the more noticeable this will be.

If you MUST have coloured text then you want to use a single solid colour wherever possible. This a process colour (cyan, magenta, yellow) unless you can add a spot Pantone colour to use for the text. Again, this should only be used as a solid.

If none of the above options are acceptable, then you can somewhat mitigate the issues by using less process colours (so that there are less colours that need to register) and making at least one of them a solid (to get crisper shapes). For your example colour this could be done by changing removing the cyan and changing the yellow to a solid. This is far from ideal, but every little helps.

There are good reasons why text usually black!

Comment: Many reliable professional printers will tell you the smallest type sizes to use for process color, reverse, etc.